# Where can I find open data related to hitchhiking?

Tags: data-request, transportation

Hitchhiking is the art of finding free rides. (I'm not interested in paid ride shares.)

[Hitchwiki Maps](http://hitchwiki.org/maps) has an [API](http://hitchwiki.org/maps/about_api).

There's also an [API for Hitchwiki articles](http://hitchwiki.org/en/api.php) but the data is not always structured well enough.

Where can I find more open data sources related to hitchhiking? Any kind of information would be useful: legal, geographical, sociological, etc.

Comment: Please be more specific as to what information you are looking for regarding hitchhiking. Also, it would be more useful to others if include the resources you've tried in your original question as opposed to in a separate answer. Having even one answer can also cause some folks to not even look and help as the question has been answered.

Comment: Ah right. Merged the answer into the question and added some more. Might add more later.

Comment: did you see the db dumps? http://hitchwiki.org/en/Hitchwiki:Database_dumps

Comment: Before we started getting innundated w/ the whole 'web 3.0' or 'the sharing web' or whatever buzzword they're using these days ... there used to be some websites out there for sharing rides ... of the sort of "I'm going to (x) event (concert / convention / whatever), and can I catch a ride?".  You also have concepts like '[slug lines](http://www.slug-lines.com/)' in the DC area, where people gather at designated locations, and drivers can pick people up so they can qualify for HOV lanes.